# Importing function from module with same name in same directory

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, python-module

I have a project directory structure that looks like this:

```
project/
    __init__.py
    mod.py
    test_mod.py
```

Where `mod.py` contains:

```
def mod():
    return
```

and `test_mod.py` contains:

```
from mod import mod

mod()
```

and `__init__.py` is left blank.

When I run `test_mod.py` I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

If I change `from mod import mod` to `from . import mod` I get:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'mod'
```

And if I change that to `from .mod import mod` I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.mod'; '__main__' is not a package
```

What is the appropriate way to import a function with the same name as the module from a script in the same directory? Should I put something in `__init__.py`?

Comment: This works for me:

    from mod import mod

Comment: Huh.. I'll have to see why in my specific case it's giving me an error and update the question accordingly